# Парсер парсит одну и ту же страницу

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Я честно, не понимаю в чем проблема. Сначала покажу код, а потом опишу проблему

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
things = dict()
count = 0

for npage in range(1, 10):
    general_link = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q={0}#p{1}_{2}'.format('', npage, '')

    req = requests.get(general_link)
    response = BS(req.content, 'html.parser')

    for answer in response.select('.market_listing_row_link'):
        href = answer.get('href')
        name2 = answer.find("span", {'class': 'market_listing_item_name'})
        name = name2.get_text()
        #   name_of_game = answer.select('.market_listing_game_name')
        name_of_game2 = answer.find("span", {'class': 'market_listing_game_name'})
        name_of_game = name_of_game2.get_text()
        count_on_tm3 = answer.find("span", {'class': 'market_listing_num_listings_qty'})
        count_on_tm2 = count_on_tm3.get_text()
        count_on_tm1 = count_on_tm2.replace(",", '')
        count_on_tm = int(count_on_tm1)
        price3 = answer.select('span[class=normal_price]')
        price2 = price3[0].get('data-price')
        price = int(price2)
        things[count] = {'name': name, 'name_of_game': name_of_game, 'count_on_tm': count_on_tm, 'price': price, 'href': href}
        count = count + 1
        '''
        print(name)
        print(name_of_game)
        print(count_on_tm)
        print(price)
        print(href)
        print('')
        '''
print(things)
```

Ссылка на сайт - https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=#p1_

Я начинаю парсить сайт, все работает прекрасно, за исключением одного "но"!
Парсер парсит **всегда одну и ту же страницу**. И не важно, что написано в ссылке, он всегда парсит 1 страницу маркета. В коде проблем вроде как нет. Может быть, существует какая-то антипарсинговая функция на сайте. Не знаю. Помогите решить, пожалуйста!

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/360229

Comment: @vp_arth Да, это приемлемый комментарий.

Comment: Так это не то. У меня проблема, что при парсинге не меняется страница парсинга. Я пока только занимаюсь парсингом товаров со страницы маркета, а не сам товар)))

Comment: `#p{1}_{2}` - часть после хеша вообще не уходит на сервер, Вам бы вместо «парсинга» найти нормальный API. Он существует. Примеры: [1](https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=578080&norender=1&count=500), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394279/2110496)

Comment: Ага, спасибо за #. То есть, я как понимаю, можно брать только данные сразу только товара, то есть брать данные с главных страниц невозможно. Или я все неправильно понял?

Comment: вы можете посмотреть во вкладке Network в Developers Tools, где приложение берёт данные. Там понятный запрос + сразу рекомендация, как получать данные вместо html)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Завтра попробую, если не может, завтра напишу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#p{1}_{2}` - часть после хеша вообще не уходит на сервер.
Очевидно, что это некий сорт SPA, который подтягивает данные через Ajax.

В Инструментах разработчика, во вкладке Сеть можно увидеть запрос к серверу за данными:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на ключ `tip` в ответе. Для Вашего же удобства, разработчики API рекомендуют добавить ключ `norender=1`, чтобы получить сырые данные вместо скраппинга HTML.
Для пагинации, судя по всему используются параметры `start/count`.

[Пробуем](https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=20&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&norender=1), работает.

Comment: Понял, что вообще ничего не знаю, придется столько изучать. Вот только вопрос, у меня около 200 таких "файлов" отобразилось, но не где нет ?query . Что делать?

Comment: И то есть, какая и понимаю, этот файл - это html версия сайта, без графики, так?

Comment: Очистить список, а потом нажать переход на другую страничку в пагинации)

Comment: Нет, это серверный API, который доставляет данные в клиентскую часть приложения)

Comment: Насчет Api понял, а вот как найти ?query не понял.

Comment: Я просто не очень уже под ночь соображаю

Comment: Ложись спать, утро вечера мудренее)

Comment: Можно ничего не искать, а взять запрос из моего ответа по ссылке «Пробуем»

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо